# Implementing a C DLL in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

I am struggling to implement a function from a C dll. It is declared as

```
int DetectTransactionCode(wchar_t* wi_type, wchar_t* wi_id);
```

If have declared and called this in my delphi code as

```
function DetectTransactionCode (var wi_type, wi_id: PWideChar): Integer;
     cdecl; external 'WiGroupDetect.dll';

procedure TForm20.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var witype,wi_id : widestring;
res : integer;
begin
 res := DetectTransactionCode(PWideChar(witype),PWideChar(wi_id));
 showmessage(res.tostring);
 ShowMessage(witype +' & ' +wi_id);
end;
```

I am receiving the result however my witype and wi_id cause access violations.

I have also tried :

```
Function  DetectTransactionCode (var witype,wi_id :widestring ) : Integer cdecl;
                  external 'WiGroupDetect.dll';

procedure TForm20.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var witype,wi_id : widestring;
 res : integer;
begin
 res := DetectTransactionCode(witype,wi_id);
 showmessage(res.tostring);
 ShowMessage(witype +' & ' +wi_id);
end;
```

I assume both parameters are out parameters. The 3rd party supplied the following :

Returns 1 for success, 0 for cancellation/failure

Note: Blocking call only returns when:
    1 - A wiCode is detected,
    2 - The KillDetectionProcess()is called, 
3 – Some error or failure occurs, or
    4 - Ultimately the timeout (30 minutes) expires.

Parameters:
wi_type Returns the type of token retrieved (i.e. “WIQR” for QR) on success; or “NONE” on cancellation/failure.
wi_id   Returns the wiCode detected on success; “CANCELLED” on cancellation; or with additional error information on failure (i.e. “ERROR: ...”).

I have tried changing the parameters to ansistring, unicodestring but still get the same problem. I suspect it has something to with the var parameter but not sure how to overcome it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have been given a C sample implementation by them

```
[DllImport("WiGroupDetect.dll", EntryPoint = "DetectTransactionCode", CallingConvention =             CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int DetectTransactionCode([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]  StringBuilder strWITYPE, [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder strUID);
```

Not sure if this changes my Delphi implementation

Comment: Default calling convention is `cdecl` in C/C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two parameters are of type `wchar_t*` which is a pointer to 16 bit character. Normally that would mean a pointer to null-terminated array of wide UTF-16 characters.

So, the correct translation of the code as presented is:

```
function DetectTransactionCode (wi_type, wi_id: PWideChar): Integer;
    cdecl; external 'WiGroupDetect.dll';
```

You used `var` parameters of type `WideString`. That would match parameters that are pointers to `BSTR` which is quite different.

I'm assuming the `cdecl` calling convention, the default for every C compiler that I have encountered. If you have some extra information that says the function is `stdcall`, so be it. But as written in the question this is `cdecl`.

It's not clear how the data flows. Are the two string parameters in or out? Is one in and the other out? If either are out parameters then you need some way to know how big a buffer to allocate. The fact that the function does not let you pass the buffer length suggests that the data flows in. That said, in that case the parameters should have been `const wchar_t*` in the C code. There's a lot of uncertainty here. Do be aware that the function prototype does not completely define the semantics of a function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have added some extra detail from the 3rd party. I assume both parameters are out parameters based on their information but I am not sure how this would change the Delphi function declaration.

Comment: The parameter semantics don't change the declaration, rather they change how you call the function. You need to allocate character arrays which are then populated by the function, if the data flows out. How long must those arrays be? We cannot answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David for your answers they helped. I managed to come right using this code. I am aware that if the string passed back is longer than I have provided for then there will be an error

```
function DetectTransactionCode (wi_type, wi_id: pwidechar): Integer;
stdcall; external 'WiGroupDetect.dll';

procedure TForm20.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var witype,wi_id :  widestring;
 res : integer;
begin
 setlength(witype,10);
 setlength(wi_id,100);
 res := DetectTransactionCode(pwidechar(witype),pwidechar(wi_id));
 showmessage(res.tostring);
 setlength(witype,pos(#0,witype)-1);
 setlength(wi_id,pos(#0,wi_id)-1);
 ShowMessage(trim(witype) +' & ' +trim(wi_id));
end;
```

Comment: You should stop using `WideString`. That's for COM interop. Use `string` which is an alias for `UnicodeString`. Personally I'd use fixed length arrays for the function call, and then assign them to string variables. And so avoid any calls to `SetLength` and `Pos`.

Comment: Indeed: `var witype, wi_id: array[0..WhateverIsSuitable - 1] of WideChar;` would be the better choice. These can directly be assigned to a string, if needed. And instead of `SetLength( witype, Pos(#0, witype) - 1)`, Oliver can either use `Setlength(witype, StrLen(witype))` or, better, `s := witype;`. If `witype` is an `array[...] of Char`, then it is even possible to use it directly in `Trim()`. The needed conversions will be done implicitly.

Comment: Thanks , I have changed the function to use array[0..100 ] of WideChar and used string instead of widestring. Your help is much appreciated.